# To Repository or Not To Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

When I first learnt about Domain Driven Design, I was also introduced to the repository and unit of work patterns that once seemed to be top notch for the cool kids that threw SQL queries like cavemans against databases. The deeper I got into that topic, the more I learnt that they don't seem to be necessary anymore because of *ORMs* like **EF** and **NHibernate** that implement both unit of work and repositories into one API, called session or context.

Now I'm unsure what to do. To repository or not to repository. I really understand the argument that such leaky abstractions only over-complicate things while adding absolutely nothing that may simplify data access, however, it doesn't feel right to couple every possible aspect of my application to e.g. **Entity Framework**. Usually, I follow a few simple guidelines:

1. The domain layer is the heart of the system, containing entities, services, repositories...
2. The infrastructure layer provides implementations of domain interfaces of a infrastructural concern, e.g. file, database, protocols..
3. The application layer hosts a composition root that wire things up and orchestrates everything.

My solutions usually look like this:

```
Domain.Module1
Domain.Module2
    IModule2Repo
    IModule2Service
    Module2
Infrastructure.Persistence
    Repositories
        EntityFrameworkRepositoryBase
MyApp
    Boostrapper
        -> inject EntityFrameworkRepositoryBase into IRepository etc.
```

I keep my domain layer clean by using a `IRepository<'T>` which is also a domain concern not depending on anything else that tells me how to access data. When I now would make a concrete implementation of `IModule2Service` that requires data access, I would have to inject `DbContext` and by this, coupling it directly to the infrastructure layer.
(*Coming to Visual Studio project, this can end up really tricky because of circular dependencies!*)

**Additionally** What can be an alternative to *depositories* and *fucktons of works*? CQRS? How does one abstract a pure infrastructural framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Depository" lol....

Anyways, you got right the bit that you don't want the domain coupled to EF that's why the *T* in your repository interface should be **domain aggregate root** and **NOT** an EF entity (or a 'domain' object designed to work properly with EF).

Your Domain layer is never coupled to persistence because it only knows about abstractions. When *Module2Service* needs data access it either uses a DAO (or a repository - not necessarily the DDD version - if it makes sense) or the service itself is an implemented in DAL (if it doesn't contain business logic).

In your case probably the best approach is the DAO/repository which of course will 'hide' the EF part. If it seems you're writing too much code, you really aren't and I think it matters the most to keep the proper separations of concerns than saving 50 LoC (a whole 5-10 minutes).

CQRS is always  good idea with a rich domain but as any solution it comes to the drawback that it requires more code (and I understand that every coder is lazy by definition, but we are required to do a 'fuckton' of work, an app doesn't build itself, a maintainable app is even more work at the beginning). 
If by abstracting a pure infrastructural framework you mean hiding EF, the repository is your best bet and you don't even have to name the class 'repository', it's the principle that matters and that's what the repo does: abstracts persistence for the Domain.

Comment: "*why the T in your repository interface should be domain aggregate root and NOT an EF entity*" -> I never thought about it that way. This changes everything!